# How is the impulse-response function of a given system related to the autocorrelation function?

Tags: autocorrelation, impulse-response

If I have the autocorrelation function of an observed system output, how does this relate to the impulse-response function of that system, if I don't have information about the input?

Comment: Do you know the system input?  e.g. was it white noise?

Comment: @BrianBorchers - no, I am assuming I don't know the system input.

Comment: This question might elicit more responses on dsp.SE. Consider asking the moderators to _migrate_ the question there. You can contact the moderators by clicking on the `flag` link below your question.

Comment: clarification question: when you say "impulse response", to me it implies an input.  Can you confirm or reject that?

Answer (score 1):

The autocorrelation function $R_y$ of the system output $y(t)$ is
related to the *autocorrelation* function $R_h$ of the system impulse
response $h(t)$ and the *autocorrelation* function $R_x$
of the system input $x(t)$ as
$$R_y = R_h \star R_x \tag{1}$$ where $\star$ denotes the convolution operation.
But note that because $R_h$ and $R_x$ are (real-valued)
*even* functions of time with a peak at the origin
(as indeed is $R_y$), we can also think of the result as saying that
$R_y$ is the *cross-correlation* function of $R_h$ and $R_x$. 
Unfortunately, all this does not help you very much if all you
know is $R_y$ and have no idea what $R_x$ is (or possibly even
what $x(t)$ might have been).  If $x(t)$ is indeed white noise
with autocorrelation function $R_x(\tau) = K\delta(\tau)$ where
$\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac impulse, then you can estimate
$R_h(\tau) = K^{-1}R_y(\tau)$ which is progress of sorts, but
it is still not possible to say *exactly* what the impulse response
$h(t)$ might be. Quite *different* signals can have the *same*
autocorrelation function: that is, knowledge of $R_h(\tau)$ does
not tell us what $h(t)$ is, though it does reduce the possibilities
considerably.

Comment: context helps.  Also I speak with the jargon of engineering courses, and need to type less when distracted.  thanks for asking for clarification.  "The output of the system whose input is the dirac delta is the transfer function of the system".  Do the algebra, and you will see how the dirac input makes the output equal to the transfer function.  By algebra I mean the symbolic manipulations in the sense of "algebrist" versus "geometer".

Comment: @EngrStudent You have deleted your previous comment with many incorrect statements and now contend only that _"The output of the system whose input is the dirac delta is the transfer function of the system"._ Unfortunately, this is _not true_ either, and "doing the algebra", as you suggest, does not produce the claimed result, regardless of whether engineering jargon is used or not. So, how about taking the time to **write out** _your_ proof, perhaps as a separate answer (where you will have more space to type in things), so that we all can study it?

Comment: If you recommend a change to my answer, or clarification, can you comment on it?  Did I misunderstand that you thought the answer might be meaningful?  If you had a chance to review the references, can you comment on how they align with the content of the answer?

Comment: @EngrStudent I don't really have a recommendation for changes to your answer. You have correctly written out the details about Dirac deltas and the like. Your results don't help much in answering the question asked by the OP (which is, in fact, unanswerable, as Brian Borchers said in his answer), but, as you will see, this question has not received much attention here -- no up or down votes at all -- and is unlikely to get any. It would be a better fit on dsp.SE but the OP did not bother to follow up on my suggestion that he ask the moderators to migrate it there.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer from the context of control systems engineering (CSE).  If your vocabulary means something different than what it does in CSE then the following answer might not be as useful.

I'm writing it out, because @Dilip_Sarwate suggests it is relevant as an answer.

The following is often applied to "Linear Time-invariant" (LTI) systems, but because of the instantaneous nature of the Dirac-delta, it can apply with linearization to any system that can be linearized, or to non-linear, non time-invariant systems as long as the derivative of the transfer function exists.  Nearly all real-world physics is governed by the 5 conservation laws (energy, mass, linear momentum, angular moment, and entropy) which can all be expressed in derivative therms.

I'm assuming you don't need me to show the relationship between the Laplace transform and the convolution operation.  If that is not the case, let me know.

The impulse response is defined as the response of a system to a Dirac-delta input, at least in control system engineering.  It is contrasted against the step-response which is the integral of the Dirac-delta over time.  The step response is less directly non-physical, and can often be physically approximated.  To a person in CSE the "I don't know the input" and "impulse response" are incompatible.

Definition of convolution([1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html)):
$$ \left[ f *g \right] = \int_{0}^{t} f\left( \tau \right) g\left(t-\tau \right) d \tau $$

property of integral of dirac delta shown in (2) and (3) of ([2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html))

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f\left( x \right) \delta\left(x-a \right) dx = f \left( a \right) $$

and

$$\int_{-a - \varepsilon }^{a+\varepsilon } f\left( x \right) \delta\left(t-a \right) dx = f \left( a \right) $$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

If we convolute $f$ with a Dirac-delta, we get:

$$ \left[ f *\delta \right] = \int_{0}^{t} f\left( \tau \right) \delta\left(t-\tau \right) d \tau $$

which upon substitution evaluates to:

$$\int_{0 }^{t } f\left( \tau \right) \delta\left(\tau - t \right) d\tau = f \left( t \right) $$

If you give a differentiable system $f$ a Dirac-delta input $g$, and if you can adequately measure the system response (measurability, sampling, discretization are sufficiently capable), then you are directly measuring the system transfer function as defined in CSE.

Here are some extra references. ([3](http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/Convolution.pdf), [4](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~dwm/Courses/2TF_2011/2TF-N3.pdf), [5](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/dsp-book/dsp_book_Ch7.pdf))

PS: [Dr. Ron Adrian](https://webapp4.asu.edu/directory/person/772992) covered this in one of his lectures during the Fluid Mechanics Measurement course[MAE 504](https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/course?s=MAE&n=504&c=TEMPE&t=2141&f=PSA108&r=26577).  I would like to think I am presenting it well, but I am quite sure there is room for improvement.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write it all out, but it shows that response of a linear time-invariant system to a Dirac delta (also called an impulse) is the **impulse response**  and **not** the _system transfer function_.  as you have been claiming.  The _system transfer function_ is the Fourier transform (or LaPlace transform) of the impulse response. Your references say that the response of an LTI system to an impulse is called the _impulse response_, and they don't call the impulse response the system transfer function. Your claim is false even in your restricted CSE sense of the words.

Comment: the dirac delta is the "identity function of the convolution operation".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unsolvable.

Suppose that the autocorrelation of the output of the system is a delta function centered at 0.  This can happen if the output of the system is white noise.  Now, you can imagine infinitely many ways of creating this white noise output with different combinations of inputs and impulse response of the system.  For example, you could use any variety of colored noise as the input and then have the system filter the noise back to whiteness.

Comment: "could use any variety of colored noise as the input and then have the system filter the noise back to whiteness."  But unless the colored noise has a PSD with a _floor_ of white noise (i.e. $S(f) > M$ for **all** frequencies $f$) for some positive number $M$), the system will need to provide _infinite_ gain at some frequencies to change the colored noise to whiteness.